# Write a program to count characters from a file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <varargs.h>
#include <ctype.h>

....................

        c = toupper(c);

        if (c == 'A')
            alphabet[0]++;


    printf("Letter Frequency\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        printf("%c %d\n", (char)(i+'A'), alphabet[i]);
    }
}
```

What I'm having trouble with, is counting all the different letters and having this carry over to the output of the file.

When I comment out this line: `c = toupper(c);` it seems to work well but for A only. I would rather have a way of doing all the letters automatically rather than typing A to Z.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In general, `printf( "error message" );` is always wrong.  Errors belong on stderr, so it should be `fprintf(stderr ,"error message");`.  In this specific case, use either `perror(argv[1])` or `fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: %s", argv[0], argv[1], strerror(errno));`

Comment: Is there any problem adding case statement for A to Z. I don't understand how you want computer to work without telling (typing) it what to do.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: `while ((c= getc(fptr)) != EOF) ` need `{ }`. Also  `char c;` --> `int c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at your loop.  There are no braces after the `while`, so the body only contains the line `c = toupper(c);`.  You need to add braces to add the `if` block to the loop as well.

To update the array, subtract the character in question from `'A'`.  You're doing the opposite when you print, so I'm surprised you didn't think of this.  This will give you the index in the array.

```
while ((c= getc(fptr)) != EOF) {
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        alphabet[c - 'A']++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to make it cleaner: `if (isupper(c))` instead of `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to map `'A'` to the number `0`, `'B'` to the number `1`, and so on. The obvious way is to create the mapping by hand.

But you can avoid the manual work. Assuming that the characters `'A'` to `'Z'` are consecutive and in ascending order in your implementation (typically they are), there is an expression that will handle the above mapping uniformly. For a variable character `c`, that expression is `c-'A'`.

```
if('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {
    alphabet[c-'A']++;
}
```

Try it for yourself. If `c` is `'A'`, then `c-'A'` is `'A'-'A'` which is obviously `0` because you're subtracting something from itself. If `c` is `'B'` (alternatively `'A' + 1`), then `c-'A'` is `'B'-'A'`, which is `'A'+1-'A'`, which is `1`. And so on.

Comment: Many thanks. I've just tried the code with a text file and it's not reading the letters. (The contents of the file are BBBB ccc). Any ideas?

Comment: post your new code in a new question. Also use a debugger to step through the program and watch what its doing